# Route traffic between two interfaces on windows server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, routing

I have windows server and having two NIC lets say NIC1 and NIC2, I want to use one NIC for internet and other for my SIP traffic.
NIC is used for Internet and its IP is as follow
IP Pool: 192.168.0.0/24
GateWay: 192.168.0.1
Server IP : 192.168.0.220

NIC2 is configured for SIP and its IPs are as follw
IP Pool: 10.227.202.24/29
Gateway: 10.227.202.25
Service IP: 10.227.202.26

But when I try to ping or access sip trunk ip (10.102.201.2) it is not accessbile, when I try to trace, it is going from interface1 (internet pool). Although default route with lowest materic set for NIC2 but it is still going out from NIC1.

Please share what route should I set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms you can't have more than one active default gateway, so in your case NIC1 has clearly been selected as the default.

There's a lot of answers covering the topic here regarding multiple default gateways - [Can a PC have more than one Default Gateway?](https://serverfault.com/questions/347032/can-a-pc-have-more-than-one-default-gateway)

Since NIC2's IP and that of the SIP trunk are on completely different IP ranges, traffic for the SIP trunk will be routed via the default gateway, unless you manually add a route within Windows to tell it that any traffic to that network should go via NIC2.

Something like (in an elevated cmd prompt) :

`route -p add 10.102.201.2 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.227.202.26`

to route all traffic for that specific SIP trunk IP via NIC2 or

`route -p add 10.102.201.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.227.202.26`

to route the entire /24 via NIC2